# Add new SalesLine to existing SalesOrder - MS Dynamics AX 2012 - AIF (C#)

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I need to add `SalesLine` to an existing `SalesOrder`. `SalesOrder` do not have any `SalesLine` yet. I am using `AIF` in CSharp (C#). I am using following code but I am getting following exceptions (checked through Dynamics AX Exceptions window) .

1. Error found when validating record.
2. Update has been canceled.

Here is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.KeyField keyField = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.KeyField() { Field = "SalesId", Value = "SO-015749" };
        SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.EntityKey entityKey = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.EntityKey();
        entityKey.KeyData = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.KeyField[1] { keyField };
        SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.EntityKey[] entityKeys = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.EntityKey[1] { entityKey };
        SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.SalesOrderServiceClient _Client;
        using (_Client = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.SalesOrderServiceClient())
        {
            SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.CallContext _callContext = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.CallContext();
            _callContext.Company = "ART";
            SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdSalesOrder _SalesOrderList = _Client.read(_callContext, entityKeys);
            SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_SalesTable _SalesOrderTable = _SalesOrderList.SalesTable.First();
            SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_SalesLine salesLine = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_SalesLine();

            salesLine.ItemId = "PF507028";
            salesLine.SalesQty = 1;
            salesLine.SalesUnit = "ea";
            salesLine.SalesId = "SO-015749";
            salesLine.RecId = _SalesOrderTable.RecId;
            salesLine.RecVersion = _SalesOrderTable.RecVersion;

            SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_InventDim inventDim = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_InventDim();
            inventDim.InventSiteId = "1";
            inventDim.InventLocationId = "13";

            salesLine.InventDim = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_InventDim[1] { inventDim };
            _SalesOrderTable.SalesLine = new SalesOrderCreateReadFindUpdateDelete.AxdEntity_SalesLine[1] { salesLine };

            _Client.update(_callContext, entityKeys, _SalesOrderList);
            lblOutput.Text += "<br />Success";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblOutput.Text += "<br />Exception: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? If I have to provide more fields then where can check these required fields in MS Dynamics. I am new to MS Dynamics.

Please Help! Thank you.

Comment: This will help. In your case you are updating header and inserting lines i.e partial update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049220/updating-a-salesorder-using-aif  https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2014/01/21/creating-sales-orders-via-aif-in-ax2012

Comment: I already have gone through these links. In fact my code is based upon these links, but its not working and giving **Update has been canceled.**

Comment: Remove below two lines as I think this is not required.

    salesLine.RecId = _SalesOrderTable.RecId;
    salesLine.RecVersion = _SalesOrderTable.RecVersion;

Modify below line to make sure same sales order is getting updated.

    salesLine.SalesId = _SalesOrderTable.SalesId;

Add below four lines for partial update.

    _SalesOrderTable.action = AxdEnum_AxdEntityAction.update; 
    _SalesOrderTable.actionSpecified = true; 
    
    salesLine.action = AxdEnum_AxdEntityAction.create; 
    salesLine.actionSpecified = true;

Comment: I did what you wrote above. 
Now I am getting a changed exception which is **Invalid entity action.**

Comment: Configure troubleshooting options for integration ports https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202045.aspx  Then please  check document log and exception log https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834439.aspx https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834351.aspx To debug https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/06/04/debugging-services-in-ax-2012/

Comment: @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu Consider creating an answer with all the hints you have given in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are updating header and inserting lines i.e partial update. Refer below links for code samples.
[Updating a salesorder using AIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049220/updating-a-salesorder-using-aif)
https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2014/01/21/creating-sales-orders-via-aif-in-ax2012

In your code I suggets to remove below two lines as I think this is not required.

```
salesLine.RecId = _SalesOrderTable.RecId; 
salesLine.RecVersion = _SalesOrderTable.RecVersion;
```

Then modify below line to make sure same sales order is getting updated.

```
salesLine.SalesId = _SalesOrderTable.SalesId;
```

Add below four lines for partial update (Header update and line creation).

```
_SalesOrderTable.action = AxdEnum_AxdEntityAction.update;
_SalesOrderTable.actionSpecified = true; 
salesLine.action = AxdEnum_AxdEntityAction.create; 
salesLine.actionSpecified = true;
```

Configure troubleshooting options for integration ports so that you can verify the logs.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202045.aspx

Please verify document log and exception log to see the values passed to Ax.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834439.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834351.aspx

To debug AIF refer msdn blog.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/06/04/debugging-services-in-ax-2012/